# WPF .Net Core 3.1 WPF Conversion Not going Well (Fun Quesiton!!)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core-3.1

I am converting a WPF App from Framework 4.7.2 to .NetCore 3.1

Entire project all source under discussion is here:
https://github.com/BicycleMark/LatestSweeper

I am using the side by side / same folder technique so that both Framework and new Core can use same project and subfolders.

Sweeper.csproj
SweperCore.csproj

exist in same folder
[image]

the Sweeper.csproj compiles and runs just fine as before.

The SweeperCore.csproj comes back with:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   NETSDK1005  Assets file 'D:\Src\Github\Sweeper\Sweeper\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 
'.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp3.1' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.    SweeperCore C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    234
```

I have examined that it is not about the packages as csproj references no pkg files.

Here is the .NetCore SweperCore.csproj contents:

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <OutputPath>bin_core\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>out_core\Debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is the image from Framework app:
[image]

Comment: Are you using both projects side by side? (e.g. 2 instances of Visual Studio?)
Then they will get in each others way and create some obscure results. Try adding `<OutputPath>bin_core\Debug\</OutputPath>` and `<IntermediateOutputPath>out_core\Debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>` to `SweperCore.csproj` to seperate their work.

Comment: @halliba  Side by side means i have a single solution SLN with two csproj under its root in same folder. Sweeper.csproj SweperCore.csproj

Comment: @halliba I tried your suggestion did not work  as same error  
 :<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
 <OutputPath>bin_core\Debug\</OutputPath>
 <IntermediateOutputPath>out_core\Debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Comment: Yes, but if MSBuild runs both project builds "at the same time", core 3.1 will use files that have been created by net472 and vice versa. Try to unload the net472 project and clean both folders manually, then rebuild netcoreapp3.1

Comment: @halliba... Valid point that is why i switched the OutpoutFolders and intermediateFolders. Good Sugestion But i have same error. The source code is up at url so you can go beyond theory... https://github.com/BicycleMark/LatestSweeper/tree/master/Sweeper and the changes you suggested are in the latest

Comment: @halliba oops I reread what you said and it worked !!!  I unloaded other (framework Project) So go ahead and post as answer and I will mark as answered! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have encoded the full answer in a tip and trick on CodeProject

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5272662/Simple-Side-By-Side-Migration-Project-Template-for

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**
The net472 and the netcoreapp3.1 projects are both using the ./obj/ folder for intermediate build files. Obviously this is a problem, if both projects are loaded in Visual Studio.

**Solution**
Replace the `IntermediateOutputPath` or `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` (both should work) for one project. This will make side by side usage in Visual Studio possible. I've cloned your repo and managed to build both apps sucessfully without unloading one of them.

Due to the fact that the BaseIntermediateOutputPath must be evaluated before any Microsoft.Common properties are being used, overriding it needs more work, than I've expected:

Modify the `SweeperCore.csproj` as followed:

Remove the Sdk Attribute in the root Project Tag:

```
<Project>
```

Add the following `PropertyGroup` and `Import` as the first childs of `<Project>`

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>obj_core</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop" Project="Sdk.props" />
```

Add this PropertyGroup to remove the net472 `out/` folder from the core app:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="obj\**" />
  <EmbeddedResource Remove="obj\**" />
  <None Remove="obj\**" />
  <Page Remove="obj\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Add this `Import` as the last child before `</Project>`.

```
<Import Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop" Project="Sdk.targets" />
```

Original Source: https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/1603

Comment: @haliba Could you post your final SweeperCore.csproj as part of your answer?

Comment: I clicked answer too fast... Now SweeperCore.csproj doesnt load when I follow the above instructions....

Comment: I missed one stepp I am all cool now... I pushed to repo and it is up there